# What is the big differences between export apk and the build apk generated in bin folder of eclipse

Tags: android

I read [What is the difference between the apk file in the bin folder and the apk file created through the Export option in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709417/what-is-the-difference-between-the-apk-file-in-the-bin-folder-and-the-apk-file-c) but I want to know are there any differences in performance between  export apk and the  build apk that generated in bin folder of eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a very very minor difference in performance if you've followed the guidelines and enclosed all debug statements withing wrappers like:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //log
}
```

Even if you have, the performance difference will be negligible to a human.

Other than that, the only difference is in the keystore used to sign the apk, and the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` boolean's value.

Exporting an apk also runs the [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) tool on it, which can be used to obfuscate and clean up code and included libraries. This may result in a slight performance increase and/or apk file size decrease.

Answer (score 1):

The apk generated in the bin directory is mainly for debugging purposes. Your `BuildConfig.DEBUG` variable is still set to true so if you have any logging or debugging messages attached to it they will execute. When you export your apk `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is set to false, skipping logging and debugging messages. It also runs your apk through proguard which, if properly configured, can remove unused/unreachable code and library dependencies, as well as obfuscate your app if you so desire. In the end you have a leaner, more efficient apk.

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard is only run on the export APK, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709594/1676363) on your linked question.

ProGuard optimization, such as explained [in this article](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html), **can** increase the speed of your application by doing some optimization, but is mostly used for size reduction (as ProGuard can strip out unused functions, etc).